# Problems parsing a table inside an RTF file using Apache Tika

Tags: java, parsing, rtf, apache-tika

I'm trying to parse a RTF file using Apache Tika. Inside the file there is a table with
several columns.

The problem is that the parser writes out the result without any information in which column the value was.

What I'm doing right now is:

```
AutoDetectParser adp = new AutoDetectParser(tc);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
String mimeType = new Tika().detect(file);
metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

adp.parse(fis, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());

fis.close();
System.out.println(handler.toString());
```

It works but I need to know like meta-information.

Is there already a Handler which outputs something like HTML with a structure of the read RTF file?

Comment: Why are you not asking Tika for the XHTML version, but instead asking for the plain text content only, if you want a HTML version?

Comment: Maybe I´m blind and you have to google it for me! :) I cannot find how to solve this. As far as I understand it you have to use (or write your own) ContentHandler. Which is some kind of SAXEventHandler...

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that rather than asking Tika for the plain text version, then wondering where all your nice HTML information has gone, you instead just ask Tika for the document as XHTML. You'll then be able to process that to find the information you want on your RTF File

If you look at the Tika Examples or the Tika Unit Tests, you'll see this same pattern for an easy way to get the XHTML output

```
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)
             SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
    TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
    handler.setResult(new StreamResult(sw));

    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());

    String xhtml = sw.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for that hint! Now I know how to output it as XHTML. :) The problem still is, that the empty column of a row isn´t shown as - for example an empty <p></p> tag. I guess you cant achieve this. The XHTML file shows the same as the plain text file plus the tags. But again thanks for your help!